# I want to custom train a NN to detect a ball in water for the IntelRealsense d435 camera

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, realsense

So I am working with a small team that needs object detection to recognize balls in water for an autonomous boat challenge. Our team is using the Intel Realsense D435 camera and we are wondering if there is a way to custom train a pre-existing NN to recognize Balls in water or if we have to somehow do it ourselves. I know this question is very vague but I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction with intel real sense and object detection. I am aware that it comes with an example that can recognize some objects like humans or airplanes but am unsure of how to get it to recognize a ball in water or a ball at all. If you have any questions please ask and I will clarify as needed.

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for a wider variety of issues.
This is, indeed, too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest approach will be a supervised one (neural network for example)
In order to train a supervised algorithm to detect a ball, you need some kind of training data - in your case the training data will be pictures of  balls in water and the annotation would consist of bounding boxes around the ball on each sample in the training dataset. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolov2-to-detect-your-own-objects-soccer-ball-using-darkflow-a4f98d5ce5bf) is an example of a similar case (ball detection in football) and the authors provide you also with some annotated training data. 
I hope you can get some inspiration and ideas from the example provided above :)